# Write a wrapper to REST API with asyncio

Tags: python, functional-programming, asynchronous

I want understand how to correctly structure a functional asyncio-based program.

The code below wraps two external APIs to provide the client a simple `send_weather()` function. Its structure reflects my current understanding of ansynchronous programming and the *very* little I've grasped of functional programming.

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial

import aiohttp


SUCCESSFUL_PUSH = {'deleted': True}  # Value specific to fake push service


async def _post(headers, url, data):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        async with session.post(url, json=data, verify_ssl=False) as response:
            return await response.json()


async def _get(headers, url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        async with session.get(url, verify_ssl=False) as response:
            return await response.json()


def make_comms(headers):
    get = partial(_get, headers)
    post = partial(_post, headers)
    return get, post


async def _notify(post, message, user):
    url = f"https://api.keen.io/dev/null?user={user}"  # Fake push service
    return await post(url, message)


async def _find_city(get, city):
    url = f"https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search?query={city}"
    obj_list = await get(url)
    if obj_list:
        return obj_list[0]
    return None


async def _city_weather(get, city_id):
    url = f"https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/{city_id}"
    return await get(url)


async def _send_weather(get, post, city, user):
    city_data = await _find_city(get, city)
    if city_data is None:
        print("Could not find city")
        return
    forecast_data = await _city_weather(get, city_data["woeid"])
    weather = forecast_data["consolidated_weather"][0]["weather_state_name"]
    message = f"Current weather in {city}: {weather}"
    reply = await _notify(post, {"message": message}, user)
    if reply == SUCCESSFUL_PUSH:
        print(f"Current weather in {city}: {weather}")
    else:
        print(f"Push notification to {user} failed: {reply}")


def init(get, post):
    return partial(_send_weather, get, post)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HEADERS = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    get, post = make_comms(HEADERS)
    send_weather = init(get, post)
    asyncio.run(send_weather("Glasgow", "Bob"))
```

How to structure an asynchronous functional program?

Answer (score 4):

- Calling `aiohttp.ClientSession` in `_post` and `_get` is really bad. Don't do this.
- There is no `main` function, this just makes the code harder to convert into a setuptools application.
- All these `functools.partial` only hinder readability rather than enhance it.

  Just make a class.
- The code isn't very functional. And I can only imagine what a purist would have to say about `_send_weather`. There are so many side effects in one little, hard to read, function.
- There is no separation of concerns, `_find_city` and `_city_weather` are solely around getting a forecast, whilst `_notify` is sending a notification. You've mangled them into one `_send_weather` function. Not great.
- Since the code isn't functional, and this is possibly the worst project to learn functional programming on. Let's just make it so that the code is easy to read.

1. Make a `WeatherForecast` class.

   1. At instantiation, it only takes a `session`.
      This is so we can remove all those `partial`s with `self.get`.
   2. Include `get` into this class, however without the session creation part.
   3. Include `find_city` as `find_cities`, and don't mutate the output.
   4. Include `city_weather`.
   5. Change `send_weather` to `get_weather` and delegate calls to `find_city` and `city_weather`.

      It is not allowed to `print` here. All it does is get the weather for the wanted city.

      This is a helper function and so mutates the values to get the two other functions to work and to get the output as we desire. Nothing else.
2. Remove the session creation part from `post`.
3. Make a function `notify_user` that notifies the user of `city`'s `weather`.

   This is as simple as using two f-strings, to build the URL and the message.
4. Change `_send_weather` so that it takes a session, city, and user.

   To make the function easy to read, we are limited to three things in the function.

   1. Calling another function.
   2. Performing a simple `if` `else` to control data flow.
   3. Formatting output to the user - basic f-strings.

Here's how I performed the above. Which is as functional as your code. And you could argue that my functions are *more pure* than yours, as `get_weather` only gets weather. `notify_user` notifies the user. And `send_weather` only `print`s and delegates to other impure functions. None of them are pure and can't be because they all have side effects. Which pretty much makes implementing this in 'pure FP' a joke.

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial

import aiohttp

SUCCESSFUL_PUSH = {'deleted': True}  # Value specific to fake push service


class WeatherForecast:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    async def get(self, headers, url):
        async with self.session.get(url, verify_ssl=False) as response:
            return await response.json()

    async def find_cities(self, city):
        return await self.get(f"https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search?query={city}")

    async def city_weather(self, city_id):
        return await self.get(f"https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/{city_id}")

    async def get_weather(self, city_name):
        cities = await self.find_city(city_name)
        if not cities:
            return None
        forecast = await self.city_weather(cities[0]["woeid"])
        return forecast["consolidated_weather"][0]["weather_state_name"]


async def post(session, url, data):
    async with session.post(url, json=data, verify_ssl=False) as response:
        return await response.json()


def notify_user(session, city, weather, user):
    return await post(
        session,
        f"https://api.keen.io/dev/null?user={user}",
        {"message": f"Current weather in {city}: {weather}"},
    )


def send_weather(session, city, user):
    weather = await WeatherForecast(session).get_weather(city)
    if weather is None:
        print("Could not get forecast")
    else:
        reply = notify_user(session, city, weather, user)
        if reply == SUCCESSFUL_PUSH:
            print(f"Current weather in {city}: {weather}")
        else:
            print(f"Push notification to {user} failed: {reply}")


async def main():
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        send_weather(session, "Glasgow", "Bob")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Hi @Peilonrayz, thanks for your answer. you make lots of good points, however I was looking for a functional programming based solution, not object based.